# How to invoke a Layout on button click?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
        // Handle the about action

    }
```

How can I invoke a layout file inside if

Comment: What do you mean by invoke? Explain properly .

Comment: opening a layout when button is clicked

Comment: Im using navigation drawable template and I want to open a Layout file from MainActivity.java when the button is clicked.

Comment: Your question is completely unclear, well at least to me. Edit it or it will get closed.

Comment: Is there a way to open a layout file when a button is clicked??

Comment: layout should have activity or fragment, want you show pop up like screen?

Comment: You can inflate your layout using LayoutInflator.

Comment: "open a layout"? Visible a layout i guess .  Well if thats what you want then `layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` will work . and your layout should be part of that component .

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the layout definition inside your main layout in a hidden or gone state, you can activate it triggering its state

```java
Layout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I want to open new layout file

Comment: Sorry, everyone, This is my problem I want to open a gallery.xml layout file whenever a button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if this is what you are asking but if you are clicking a button in android to switch a layout this will work:

```
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           setContentView(R.layout.yourLayoutId);

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, everyone, This is my problem I want to open a gallery.xml layout file whenever a button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate a new layout using LayoutInflator.

```
if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
    // Handle the about action 
     LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater
                    .from(getApplicationContext());
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_aboutUs, null);
            //add this view to root layout
            rootLayout.addView(view);
}
```